# Switching function of UIButton

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, swift3

I have a `UIButton` and I want to case switch between functions of the button. The first case would be to print hello and the second case would be to print yes. And it will restart and keep going over and over again. I tried but I Keep failing. I tried this below but I keep getting an error of "expression pattern of type 'Int' cannot match values of type 'Bool' at case 0: and case 1:. Im trying to switch the function of the button everytime its pressed

```
func Target(sender: UIButton){

switch (true){

case 0:
    print("hello")
case 1:
    print("yes")

default:
    println("hello")
}

}
```

Comment: You have a better chance of getting a helpful reply if you post the code you've already tried to solve your problem.

Comment: Edit your question to include your code and a clearer explanation of your issue. Someone may then be able to assist you. Alternatively, use breakpoints and the debugger to step through your code to find your logic errors. As an aside, please read the FAQ on how to ask questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: its edited now can you please look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While in many languages you can use the integer values `0` and `1` for the boolean values `true` and `false`, Swift is strongly typed, so an `Int` is not a `Bool`. This is what the Swift compiler is telling you.

Additionally, you have a logic error. You are switching on the value `true`.  This is a constant so it will never be any other value; the `switch` function is irrelevant.

What you want to do is switch on the value of some other state variable where you track whether you should print 'hello' or 'yes'

```
var buttonState = false

func target(_ sender: UIButton) {
    switch self.buttonState {
        case false:
            print("hello")
        case true:
            print("yes")
    }
    self.buttonState = !self.buttonState // Invert the button state variable
}
```

Note also, that by convention, only class and struct names should start with an uppercase letter.  Properties and functions should start with a lower case letter.  Sticking to this convention will help others (and you) read your code and understand what is what.

Answer (score 0):

You can do same without taking any extra boolean value in your project. Just use button selected/unselected state.

```
func target(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if sender.isSelected{
            sender.isSelected = false
        }
        else{
            sender.isSelected = true
        }
    }
```